# Scrape emails with python 3.x from websites

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I have a script that should take a list of websites, and search for emails from there (see code below).
Every time it gets some error e.g "Website is forbidden", or "Service temporary unavailable" etc.. script will start all over again.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request, urllib.error
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
import ssl

# 1: Get input file path from user '.../Documents/upw/websites.csv'
user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")

# If input file doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(user_input):
    print("File not found, verify the location - ", str(user_input))


def sites(e):
    pass


while True:
    try:
        # 2. read file
        df = pd.read_csv(user_input)

        # 3. create the output csv file
        with open('Emails.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
            csv_writer.writerow(['Website', 'Email'])

        # 4. Get websites
        for site in list(df['Website']):
            # print(site)
            gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
            req = urllib.request.Request("http://" + site, headers={
                'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1",
                # 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive'
            })

            # 5. Scrape email id
            with urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=gcontext) as url:
                s = url.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
                email = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", s)
                print(email)

                # 6. Write the output
                with open('Emails.csv', mode='a', newline='') as file:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
                    [csv_writer.writerow([site, item]) for item in email]

    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print("Failed to open URL {0} Reason: {1}".format(site, e.reason))
```

If I remove code:

```
def sites(e):
pass

while True
```

Script stops when error occurs..

What it should do is not to stop script if error occurs from web side, instead continue searching.

I have searched the web for some time now, and looked into several posts, but looks like wrong ones as I haven't found solution for that..

Any help I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your `while True:` loop. Its always going to restart because an exception is generated in the `try` block the loop then goes to the `exception` block. After that it will loop again and run the `try` block from the very beggining.

When you take out the `While True:` then when an exception happens it will just stop the process completely because an exception will be raised in the `try` block which stops the `try` block execution and will then proceed to the `except` block and then continue on with the rest of the program.

What you want is to have the try block inside the loop where you are looping over the websites in `df['Website']` that way if an exception is thrown it will move to the next website in the list and not all the way to the beginning of reading in the dataframe and starting the looping of the websites all over again.

```py
    # 2. read file
df = pd.read_csv(user_input)

# 3. create the output csv file
with open('Emails.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writerow(['Website', 'Email'])

# 4. Get websites
for site in list(df['Website']):
    try:
        # print(site)
        gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
        req = urllib.request.Request("http://" + site, headers={
            'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1",
            # 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        })

        # 5. Scrape email id
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=gcontext) as url:
            s = url.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            email = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", s)
            print(email)

            # 6. Write the output
            with open('Emails.csv', mode='a', newline='') as file:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
                [csv_writer.writerow([site, item]) for item in email]

    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print("Failed to open URL {0} Reason: {1}".format(site, e.reason))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very well explained and it is much more clearer for me now. Everything makes sense.